# Create dependent picklist without grey out

Tags: apex, visualforce, dependent-picklist

I created some `dependent picklists` in my `custom object` and and I am trying to figure out how to display them in my `vf page` without `grey out` of the `dependent ones` and also increase the size of the `picklists`.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: May help if you share the vf you've already written so far.

Comment: I faced this "problem" few month ago and realized that it is almost impossible to enable ("grey out") the dependent picklist before selecting something in the master picklist. And that's good because SF takes over this process. Just think again whether you realy need to do this. If so the better solution is to create your own picklists (apex/visualforce) to take control over visibility/accessibility, but think twice before doing it.

Comment: Yup, It really seems Impossible. It is hectic work for me to create them using Apex and visualforce because I have so many picklist values in each of them. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you clarify why you want the lists as dependent AND not greyed out?  If you really want dependent lists your users should expect this type of presentation.

Comment: It's just a requirement. I cannot really explain you why. I'll be still interested to know how to do that.